# Events and Delegates Ceremony

Tags: f#

Can I take this statement:

```
let propertyChanged = 
    Event<PropertyChangedEventHandler,PropertyChangedEventArgs>()
```

And rename it to:

```
let propertyChangedDelegate = 
    Event<PropertyChangedEventHandler,PropertyChangedEventArgs>()
```

I'm trying to understand the ceremony of event declaration within F#.

Specifically, I am trying to understand the difference between:

```
let propertyChanged = 
    Event<PropertyChangedEventHandler,PropertyChangedEventArgs>()
```

And:

```
interface INotifyPropertyChanged with
    [<CLIEvent>]
    member this.PropertyChanged = propertyChanged.Publish
```

Here's the entire scope of code here:

```
open System.ComponentModel
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns

    type ViewModelBase () =
        let propertyChanged = 
            Event<PropertyChangedEventHandler,PropertyChangedEventArgs>()

        let getPropertyName = function 
            | PropertyGet(_,pi,_) -> pi.Name
            | _ -> invalidOp "Expecting property getter expression"

        interface INotifyPropertyChanged with
            [<CLIEvent>]
            member this.PropertyChanged = propertyChanged.Publish

        member private this.NotifyPropertyChanged propertyName = 
            propertyChanged.Trigger(this,PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))

        member this.NotifyPropertyChanged quotation = 
            quotation |> getPropertyName |> this.NotifyPropertyChanged
```

Can someone please explain to me how events are implemented in F#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In F#, events are just *values* of type `IEvent<T>` that you can pass around. So, to create an event, you need to write some implementation of this interface (which handles adding and removing event handlers).

The `Event<T>` type provides a default sensible implementation of the interface. When you write:

```
let propertyChanged = 
  Event<PropertyChangedEventHandler,PropertyChangedEventArgs>()
```

You're just using a class from the F# library that creates a new implementation of an event which accepts `PropertyChangedEventArgs` and can be used with event handlers of the delegate type `PropertyChangedEventHandler`.

The returned `propertyChanged` object has two things:

- `Publish` property gives you the `IEvent<T>` value (representing event)
- `Trigger` method invokes the event (which then invokes all the event handlers that are registered with the `IEvent<T>` value that is hidden inside the `propertyChanged` object).

So writing:

```
interface INotifyPropertyChanged with
    [<CLIEvent>]
    member this.PropertyChanged = propertyChanged.Publish
```

Is just a way of exposing the event (using the `CLIEvent` attribute to tell the F# compiler that it should be compiled as a .NET compatible event).

There is [a more detailed documentation on F# events on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233189.aspx) if you want to learn more.